# Java: Converting Class member variables/values into Map - Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap

I have an instance of a class for which I would like to create a Map which has Key as each class variable name and its Value as the value in that class variable?

I tried to use the following but it doesn't seem to work. It does not go into either the if() or the else if() section. And the maps remain empty.

Could someone figure out the issue here? Thanks

```
public class ClassA {
    private String optionOne = "1";
    private Int optionTwo = 2;

}


        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> mapInt = new HashMap<>();

        for (Field field : ClassA.class.getFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.getType().equals(String.class)){
                map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(object));
            } else if (field.getType().equals(Integer.class)) {
                mapInt.put(field.getName(), (Integer) field.get(object));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Both the maps are empty. (updated the question)

Comment: Use ```getDeclaredFields```, and it is ```int.class``` not ```Integer.class```.

Comment: @zhh ok that works for String.class now. But the int variables are not going into mapInt. is the equality check correct?

Comment: Not sure what `Int` type is - is it `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: You should check for ```int.class``` not ```Integer.class```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `getFields` to `getDeclaredFields` and `Integer.class` to `int.class` since field `optionTwo` is `int` not `Integer`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> mapInt = new HashMap<>();

for (Field field : ClassA.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if (field.getType().equals(String.class)){
        map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(object));
    } else if (field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
        mapInt.put(field.getName(), (Integer) field.get(object));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @zhh I was able to fix the issue as follows:

1. ClassA.class.getDeclaredFields() instead of ClassA.class.getFields()
2. Integer.TYPE instead of Integer.class

> ```
>  for (Field field : ClassA.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
>                 field.setAccessible(true);
>                 if (field.getType().equals(String.class)){
>                     map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(object));
>                 } else if (field.getType().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
>                     mapInt.put(field.getName(), (Integer) field.get(object));
>                 }
>             }
> ```